# AndroidStudio Code folding and optional new keyword in Dart 2

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, new-operator, folding

In Dart2 the use of `new` keyword is optional, but at 2/8/2019 Android Studio just let collapse/expand blocks if you are using `new` keyword!

[image]

Is there any plugin to solve it or we have to wait for new version of Android Studio? Because its very very useful feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue and was fixed 3 weeks ago

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35830
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2836

and should be included in the next Dart plugin version.

Comment: Thank you so much, I hope the next version will release soon.